# Is it possible to access multiple arrays in an #each loop in a handlebars file?

Tags: node.js, express

In app.js, I pass back 2 arrays of the same size to the client.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
{{#each arrayOne}}
<Li>this </Li>
<Li> {{@index : arrayTwo}} </Li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You'll probably have to prepare your datastructures to map more closely to your use case as Handlebars isn't supposed to be a scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid complex logic in your view templates. Instead, I'd recommend having a controller do the merging job for you.

That way you'd untangle the view, since its more descriptive of what you're going to display, and your controller clearly states the intent to render different data in a combined manner.

e.g

```
model.arr = arrayOne.map(function (item, i) {
  return {
    i1: arrayOne[i],
    i2: arrayTwo[i]
  };
});
```

Then your view becomes much simplified

```
{{#each arr}}
<Li>{{arr.i1.thing}}</Li>
<Li>{{arr.i2.thingie}}</Li>
{{/each}}
```

Obviously you should *improve this further* by only returning the relevant properties in your `map` callback.

Comment: I looked into map and it looks exactly like what I need. Thanks for your help.